# One Activity Appears one time Only Untill the user uninstall the Application

Tags: java, android

Am new to android ,My problem is if user enter his details once in activity ,then next time it will not appears to the user please save my day thanks in Advance

Actually i am working on Google signin integration if user register once,i am taking the user detalis in another activity,then next that activity doesn't appears yet, Thanks guys in advance..

Comment: Please write what you tried?

Comment: Give little more details of your code.

Comment: please read this **[ask]**

Comment: Actually, i am working on google integratiion

Comment: use different fragments inside activity to show different states

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That time you need to store user data into sharedpreference and check user data empty or not .if empty then show that sceen other wise is go next screen like  below that..

First activty on button click call below method..

```
    private void saveData(){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("MyData", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("name", mEt.getText().toString().trim());
    editor.apply();
}
```

then after first activity onCreate method check value like below..

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyData", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
    if (restoredText != null) {
        String name = prefs.getString("name", "No name defined");//"No name defined" is the default value.
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)){
            Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
```

and also both activity define in manifest flie like below ..

```
    <activity android:name=".FirstActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
    <activity android:name="SecondActivity"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm working on it, hope i will solve my query.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are saving user details in `SharedPreferences` , you can add one more detail in `SharedPreferences` as `boolean isUserDetailsSet`.  With the help of this `boolean` value , `true` or `false` you can decide whether to call an Activity or not.